# All posible combinations of numbers on a list

Tags: python

I need to find all the possible combinations of a list with a defined length and numbers of defined size, but subject to a restriction that does not allow having the same repeated number in the list (except 0).
Currently I have a recursive code that generates all the combinations, but when trying to create the constraints I lose many options.
I have tried the options that appear commented to solve it, but it still does not work for me. Thank you in advance for your help.

```
size=3
l=[0 for x in range(size)]

def recursive(l, index, num, final):
    if index == len(l) or num == final:
        return
#     if num!=0 and num in l:
#         return
    l[index]=num
    print(l)
    recursive(l, index+1, 0, final)
    recursive(l, index, num+1, final)
recursive(l, 0, 0, 4)
```

the expected output for a list of size 3 and final number 3 would be something like this

```
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 2]
[0, 0, 3]
[0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 3]
[0, 2, 0]
[0, 2, 1]
[0, 2, 3]
[0, 3, 0]
[0, 3, 1]
[0, 3, 2]
[1, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 2]
[1, 0, 3]
[1, 2, 0]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 0]
[1, 3, 2]
[2, 0, 0]
[2, 0, 1]
[2, 0, 3]
[2, 1, 0]
[2, 1, 3]
[2, 3, 0]
[2, 3, 1]
[3, 0, 0]
[3, 0, 1]
[3, 0, 2]
[3, 1, 0]
[3, 1, 2]
[3, 2, 0]
[3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: try [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations)

Comment: I tried, but itertools does not consider the order, [1,2,3] = [3,2,1], but in my case it is not like that

Comment: One helpful tip will be to consider that this is very similar to how you might generate numbers for a number system of base `k` using `k` elements in the list

Comment: @GuillermoMeza: `itertools` is the whole module; some of them are order-insensitive (`combinations`, `combinations_with_replacement`) some aren't (`permutations`, `product`). The whole `itertools` module is *full* of amazingly helpful utilities, if you think "it doesn't consider order", you're not looking closely enough.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the powerset of the non-zero values (a function for computing the powerset of a list can be found in the `itertools` documentation.)

```
def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))

>>> list(powerset([1,2,3]))
[(), (1,), (2,), (3,), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]
```

(You could compute the power set including 0, but you would still need to zero-pad the shorter elements, as well as discard `(0,1,2,3)`).

Each element of the powerset should next be padded with zeros so that they are all the same length.

Finally, you want the list of *permutations* (using `itertools.permutations`) of each 0-padded permutation of the original input.

Comment: How do you get all the different paddings? `(1, 3)` => `(0, 1, 3), (1, 0, 3), (1, 3, 0)`

Comment: Let `n = [1,2,3]`. Then `(1,3)` is a element of `powerset(n)`, but what you want for each element `x` is really `(x+(0,)*len(n))[:len(n)]`, which will produce `(1,3,0)`. `itertools.permutations` will give the permutations desired. (One hitch is that if the input contains duplicates, `permutations` treats them as distinct objects, so the output needs to be filtered for duplicates.)

Comment: I realize this answer is far from complete, but I'm not sure how many details I'm comfortable adding without doing too much of the assignment for the OP.

Comment: @chepner: Agreed; this is more than enough to get them going (enough that they could probably finish the assignment without fully understanding it, but only just). It's fine as is; up-voted.

Answer (score 1):

Use `itertools.combinations_with_replacement()`, and then filter out the elements with duplicates.

```
def has_duplicates(l):
    '''Return True if list has duplicate elements other than 0'''
    l = [x in l if x != 0]
    return len(l) != len(set(l))

result = [comb for comb in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(l, 3) if not has_duplicates(comb)]
```

You can make this lazy by using `itertools.filterfalse()`; this way you won't fill up memory with all combinations of a large list.

```
result = itertools.filterfalse(has_duplicates, itertools.combinations_with_replacement(l, 3))
```

Comment: I might suggest that in real code, you replace the final line with either the genexpr version of that listcomp (`()` instead of `[]`) or use `result = itertools.filterfalse(has_duplicates, itertools.combinations_with_replacement(l, 3))` to produce a lazy iterator, not an eager `list`, allowing it to be looped over and generated one at a time, so only CPU time is subject to combinatoric explosion (takes longer to run, but works), not memory usage (program runs out of memory, dies).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution based on counters, I am using a base 4 counter:

```py
def charcnt(s, a):
    ctr = [1 if x == a else 0 for x in s ]
    return sum(ctr)
    

def my_range(start,end,base,step=1):
    def Convert(n,base):
       string = "0123"
       if n < base:
          return string[n]
       else:
          return Convert(n//base,base) + string[n%base]
    return (Convert(i,base) for i in range(start,end,step))

# base-10 58 will produce base-4 321
counter = [x.zfill(3) for x in my_range(0, 58, 4)]

result = []
for s in counter:
    if charcnt(s, '1') > 1 or charcnt(s, '2') > 1 or charcnt(s, '3') > 1:
        continue
    else:
        result.append(s)

result = [[int(n) for n in list(s)] for s in result]
#print(len(result))
for i in result:
    print(i)
```

Will produce:

```sh
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 2]
[0, 0, 3]
[0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 3]
[0, 2, 0]
[0, 2, 1]
[0, 2, 3]
[0, 3, 0]
[0, 3, 1]
[0, 3, 2]
[1, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 2]
[1, 0, 3]
[1, 2, 0]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 0]
[1, 3, 2]
[2, 0, 0]
[2, 0, 1]
[2, 0, 3]
[2, 1, 0]
[2, 1, 3]
[2, 3, 0]
[2, 3, 1]
[3, 0, 0]
[3, 0, 1]
[3, 0, 2]
[3, 1, 0]
[3, 1, 2]
[3, 2, 0]
[3, 2, 1]
```